# Swift - Modifying URLSession code to work with HTTPS

Tags: ios, swift, post, https, nsurlsession

I recently implemented HTTPS on my web server but now found that my app does not work. It doesn't seem to receive any POST variables but shows no errors.

This is basically how I'm using URLSession:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://url")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
    data, response, error in

    // Convert from JSON to NSArray
    do {
        let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
        // do something
    } catch {
        return
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Obviously there's some extra stuff in setting up the POST message, but that's not too important. Everything worked fine until I changed to HTTPS.

How can I modify my code to get it working again?

Comment: This is probably because of ATS, make sure your server has the newest HTTPS (TLS 1.2 with perfect forward secrecy)

Comment: Everything is up to date, are you sure its not an issue with using https over http?

Comment: I really need help, I have to present this tomorrow and it's stopeed working

Comment: Was there any `error` object inside the closure? Edit your question to show us what it was. If it wasn't `error`, then I presume the `jsonObject` call is failing. Well, then edit your question to show us what the `data` contained (e.g., `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)`).

Comment: The code is all completely fine. The error object is nil, and the JSONSerialization works just fine. In my PHP code I am trying to return the SQL query for debugging, but there are no variables in the query. I know the problem must be in the changeover between HTTP and HTTPS. It all worked fine before then.

Comment: Finally got it working - all I needed was to add www. to front of url

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the server configuration (named virtual host issues specific to HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the root cause of the issue was that my Nginx proxy was cutting off all the unknown headers.

I resolved it by renaming my authentication header to `auth`.